# Play json parse missing field as empty array

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Using play-json 2.3
How do i parse this

```
{i: 0}
```

into this

```
case class A(i: Int, s: Seq[Int])
```

i would very much like to reuse Json.format macro

at the moment it gives me "missing path s"

UPD:
i ended up writing a custom format and pimping it onto JsPath:

```
implicit class JsPathExtensions(path: JsPath) {
  //return mzero if the path is missing
  def lazyFormatNullableM[T: Monoid](f: => Format[T]): OFormat[T] = OFormat(path.lazyReadNullable(f).map(_.orZero), new OWrites[T] {
    override def writes(o: T) = path.lazyWriteNullable(f).writes(o.some)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the path is missing, I don't see any way to utilize the macro without changing the class. In which case, you can define `Reads` using json combinators and use the macro for `Writes`.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

implicit val reads: Reads[A] = (
    (__ \ "i").read[Int] and 
    (__ \ "s").read[Seq[Int]].orElse(Reads.pure(Nil))
)(A.apply _)

implicit val writes: Writes[A] = Json.writes[A]
```

The json macros only cover a very limited range of use cases, and it's inevitable that you'll run into a case where you must write your own `Reads` or `Writes`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to utilise the `Json.format[A]` macro would be to slightly alter your definition of `A`:

```
case class A(i: Int, s: Option[Seq[Int]])
```

The usage of an `Option` here is pretty clear and you can `map` over it and do lots of good things, but if you *really* want to treat `s` like it's an empty collection, you could enhance your case class a little more:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: Option[Seq[Int]]) {
  lazy val theSeq:Seq[Int] = s.getOrElse(Seq[Int]())
}
```

Now if you access `theSeq`, there is absolutely no difference between incoming JSON that omitted `s` and JSON that supplied an empty array for `s`.

Comment: yeah, i thought about that, but changing the class is not an option

Comment: Same problem, did you find a way to force Play.json to init empty seq instead of throwing error?